# bluetooth connection in vc#.net

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming

I want to create an Bluetooth chat room for pc 
i will use visual studio 2005 as the front end 
i just want to know how do i connect one system to another system with each other 
and send data or message using an Bluetooth in vc#.net

software like intranet chatting use's LAN as connection medium
traditional way to connect to one system to another system is using LAN

i want to create intranet chatting using Bluetooth as connection medium

Comment: I wonder if you mean that you will use VS2005 to *create* the front end, or if you really mean you want to chat from VS2005 itself.

Comment: i will use vs2005 to create the front end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best method to do is to connect the two systems via bluetooth, using just windows.

And then you can add a serial port in the bluetooth manager of each computer and connect your application via Serial Port.

http://www.conniq.com/Windows-networking/Bluetooth_PAN_xp-setup_01.htm

http://www.acroname.com/garcia/tutorials/bluetooth/connection/connection.html